# How set environment variable permanently in Red Hat Linux?

Tags: environment-variables, csh

As I'm using Red Hat Linux 5.3, I'm unable to set environment variable permanently. I want the file names for `csh`, from which I can add the environment variables permanently.

Answer (score 2):

For one user, add it to `~/.cshrc`. To apply it to all users add it to `/etc/csh.cshrc`:

```
setenv PATH /opt/something-special/
setenv VARNAME some_value
```